# Problem when I try to move my WordPress blog to a new server

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to move my WordPress to a new server and domain.

1. I downloaded the whole file on old server to my computer and then uploaded it to the new server.
2. I exported all tables in the database and imported them to the new database server.
3. I edited wp-config.php by setting the new value in it.
4. I changed some columns in the new database to my new domain name.

When I go to my new website, I see problems. I can't access my website; I see popups like "download application/x-httpd-php"

How can I fix this?

Comment: "I see problems" is a bit vague. Please be explicit as to what you believe it should be doing and what it is actually doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your new server isn't configured to render PHP properly. That is why it is trying to send you the PHP file instead of running it.

Answer (score 0):

There are much easier ways to move your wordpress site to another host/domain. I have been doing this for a while, usually it only takes me less than an hour, depending on the size of the website. All done automatically just by cloning the whole wordpress site